# How to represent a group of C++ dynamically allocated objects as a BGL (Boost Graph Library) graph in order to obtain their dependency graph?

Tags: c++, boost, graph, dependencies, boost-graph

There is a group of C++ dynamically allocated objects as:

```
class MyObject;
MyObject* a = ....;
MyObject* b = ....;
MyObject* c = ....;
```

with known dependencies:

- `b` depends on `a`
- `c` depends on `b`

How those objects can be represented as simple as possible as a [BGL graph](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/graph/doc/) in order to obtain their [dependency graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_graph)?

As result the dependency graph should be a list of pointers as: `a`, `b`, `c` (or in the reverse order).

I know the dependency graph can be obtained using [boost::topological_sort](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/graph/doc/topological_sort.html). Until now I didn't found an example of a BGL graph dealing with pointers to objects. Instead I found many [examples based on integers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/graph/example/topo_sort.cpp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integers are indices to the vertices and edges of the graph.  So, in your example, the first vertex is a and the second vertex is b while the first edge connects vertices 1 and 2 ( a and b )

Each vertex has properties.  So, in your example, the first vertex is named a and has a pointer to a.

The graph algorithms use the integer indices to manipulate the graph, and your code can use the indices to get back to the properties that you are interested in, such as names and pointers.

Here is how I would code the example you posted:

```
/**

Bundled properties for graph vertices

Simply contains a pointer to the associated MyObject

*/

class cVertex
{
public:
    MyObject * pObject;
};

class cEdge
{

};

class cGraphProps
{

};

....

// The BGL graph
typedef boost::adjacency_list <
    boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS,
    cVertex, cEdge, cGraphProps  >
    graph_t;
typedef boost::graph_traits<graph_t>::vertex_descriptor vertex_t;

graph_t myGraph;

// Create objects and associate them with graph vertices
MyObject * a = new MyObject( 'a');
vertex_t va = boost::add_vertex( myGraph );
myGraph[ va ].pObject = a;
MyObject * b = new MyObject( 'b');
vertex_t vb = boost::add_vertex( myGraph );
myGraph[ vb ].pObject = b;
MyObject * c = new MyObject( 'c');
vertex_t vc = boost::add_vertex( myGraph );
myGraph[ vc ].pObject = c;

// specify the 'dependencies' between the myObjects
boost::add_edge( vb, va, myGraph );
boost::add_edge( vc, vb, myGraph );

// sort the vertices into order according to dependencies
std::deque<int> topo_order;
boost::topological_sort( myGraph, std::front_inserter(topo_order));

// Print the results.
for(std::deque<int>::const_iterator i = topo_order.begin();
    i != topo_order.end();
    ++i)
{
    std::cout << myGraph[*i].pObject->x << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Ultimately the pointers are integers and thus the pointers could be cast to integers. But looking at the examples, the integer indices should be in [0..2] interval for this case.
If this is the only way, it seems I had too high expectations from the versatility of BGL graph: [boost::adjacency_list](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/graph/doc/adjacency_list.html) has a template parameter VertexList that can be of type hash_mapS and I thought this can be used to map pointers to integer indices.

Comment: As explained in my answer, you can 'map' the pointers to the vertex indices by using the properties feature - that is what it is for.

Comment: Thank you very much! Despite the fact 'add_edge' calls still require a mapping between MyObject pointer and vertex_t, I will accept your answer because your implementation uses less auxiliary containers than mine.

Comment: how do you get the vertex descriptor `vertex_t` given the `MyObject*`?

Comment: @fferri You could search the vertices for the one that contains your object.  If that is too inefficient, you would need to add an attribute to MyObject which is set to the vertex associated with the object. a->vertex = va;

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this implementation but I would prefer a simpler one if it's possible:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/topological_sort.hpp>

class MyObject
{
public:
    char x;
    MyObject( const char c): x( c) {}
};

int main()
{
    auto a = new MyObject( 'a');
    auto b = new MyObject( 'b');
    auto c = new MyObject( 'c');

    typedef std::vector<const MyObject*> Objects;
    Objects objects;
    objects.push_back( c); // c = 0
    objects.push_back( a); // a = 1
    objects.push_back( b); // b = 2

    typedef std::vector<size_t> Indexes;
    Indexes indexes;

    {
        typedef std::unordered_map<Objects::value_type, size_t> PtrIntMap;
        PtrIntMap ptrIntMap;
        std::for_each( objects.begin(), objects.end(), [&ptrIntMap]( Objects::reference item) { ptrIntMap.insert( std::make_pair( item, ptrIntMap.size())); });

        using namespace boost;
        adjacency_list<> g( objects.size());
        add_edge( ptrIntMap.at( b), ptrIntMap.at( a), g);
        add_edge( ptrIntMap.at( c), ptrIntMap.at( b), g);

        topological_sort( g, std::back_inserter( indexes)); 
    }

    Objects dependencies( indexes.size());
    std::transform( indexes.begin(), indexes.end(), dependencies.begin(), [&objects]( Indexes::value_type index) { return objects[ index]; });
    std::for_each( dependencies.begin(), dependencies.end(), []( const Objects::value_type item) { std::cout << item->x << ' '; });
}
```

Comment: It would be simpler if you used the bundled properties feature of boost::adjacency_list, rather than trying to keep track of things with your own, separate map.

Comment: I have added to my answer how I would recode your sample to use bundled properties.